# How to adjust brightness and contrast using min and max values using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

In ImageJ you can adjust the brightness and contrast of an image using minimum and maximum values. You can also use the `setMinAndMax()` macro function. The dialog looks like this:

[image: ImageJ Brightness and Contrast dialog]

It maps each pixel to fit between the minimum and maximum values.

I'm trying to do the same thing in OpenCV (C++). I can change the contrast and brightness using the `alpha` and `beta` parameters of `Mat::convertTo()`, but I don't know how to do it with minimum and maximum values.

In my case I'm using a 12-bit image so the pixel values range from 0 to 4095. I'm not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this.

First, find the current maximum and minimum.

Let's say the darkest and brightest are 80 and 220 respectively. Now you need to stretch this range 80..220 onto the full range 0..4095.

So you subtract 80 from every pixel in your image to shift down to zero at the left end of the histogram, so your range is now 0..140.

Now you need to multiply every pixel by 4095/140 to stretch the right end out to 4095.

Effectively, the formula you need is this:

```
newvalue = int((current value - darkest)*4095/(brightest-darkest))
```

Comment: Yeah, I think both yours and @theamk's posts are correct but I needed your explanation for it to make sense. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You do it in three steps:

- get the current min/max using minMaxLoc
- adjust 'min' value by adding the difference to the image (no special function, just do 'image = image + offset' in C++ or python)
- adjust 'max' value by scaling the image (no special function, 'image = image * scale')

Comment: I think you need to subtract the offset from the current image, rather than add it.

Comment: it all depends on how you define the offset -- (new_min - old_min) or (old_min - new_min). It can work either way.