# Error changing the brightness of grayscale based on minimum and maximum values

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to process an image in OpenCV and one of those steps involve altering the brightness of the grayscale image based on the min and the max pixel intensities.

I tried using the solution in this question [How to adjust brightness and contrast using min and max values using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980979/how-to-adjust-brightness-and-contrast-using-min-and-max-values-using-opencv) but it is not working for me. I wanted a brightened grayscale image but i'm getting an inverted binary image instead.

```
img = cv2.imread(imgn, 0)

r2, img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

j, vmax, lmin, lmax = cv2.minMaxLoc(img)

img = ((img-r2)*255/(vmax-r2)).astype(np.uint16)

cv2.imshow("dfsf", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

desired output

[image: desired output]

actual output

[image: actual output]

I appreciate any help or thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please also share the input image?

Comment: `threshold` isn't really necessary, and it seems you mixed up `r2` and `j`.

Comment: @Paul92 I'm trying to edit, it's telling me that my code isn't formatted properly. sorry, will try to add asap

Comment: @busybear sorry, I should have clarified. I'm thresholding the image to remove noise first, and if I use the normal min rather than the threshold value, the minimum is 0. am i assuming incorrectly that r2 returns the otsu threshold value?

Comment: @Paul92 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fe0t.png here is a link. There's a white border since it's a screenshot (the original image is too big)

Comment: I imagine you are "wrapping around" when you subtract by `r2`. You should ensure that negative numbers from `img-r2` are changed to 0. Otherwise, casting it to an unsigned integer will result in erroneous values.

Comment: @busybear thanks! i think you might be right, do you know how to do that with numpy? it's so slow to loop through with python

Comment: You can't just grab code from other answers when your situation and data are different! Please say what the range of your input data is and what the expected output range is, e.g. my input data varies between 100..200 but I want it to be between 0..4096.

Comment: @MarkSetchell my input is 10-71 but I'd like 0-255.

Comment: It's probably simplest just to call `normalize()` with `NORM_MINMAX` - sorry I don't have exact spelling and names to hand.

Comment: You need to change the datatype of your image to something that doesn't wrap, do your numpy manipulations, and then change it back. Undoubtedly it's coming out of the opencv operation with some opencv datatype.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you so much

Comment: @kevinkayaks Yes, I figured it out eventually- it was causing some pixels to go negative and then overflow (it wasn't actually binary, it was just ridiculously high values like 65497)